# How to loop over an array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop an array that contains objects and I keep getting and error: "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined".  What am I doing wrong?

```js
var ObjectTest = function(something1, something2){
    this.Name = something1;
    this.Job = something2;
    this.color = '';
    this.numbers = [];
    
}

var first = new ObjectTest('Paul', 'teacher');
var second = new ObjectTest('Jane', 'doctor');
var third = new ObjectTest('Mike', 'student');

var someArray = [];
someArray.push(first, second, third);
console.log(someArray);


for(var i =0; i <= someArray.length; i++){
    someArray[i].color = 'red';
};
```

Comment: Your `<=` in the loop should be `<`.

Comment: Should be `i < someArray.length`. If the array has 3 elements, the length is 3 and the indexes are 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested 'for' loop - array undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331423/nested-for-loop-array-undefined)

Comment: First off -- thank you for posting a useful snippet.

The answers given below are correct -- but may I suggest that you look into learning your browser's debugging tools.  That would have allowed you to step through the loop item by item and see all the variable's and their values.  In turn, that would have led you to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate until the length of the array but not over, because indices are zero based

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
//                ^
```

An array returns `undefined` for a not existing item. `undefined` has no property to assign a new value.

```js
var ObjectTest = function(something1, something2) {
        this.Name = something1;
        this.Job = something2;
        this.color = '';
        this.numbers = [];
    };

var first = new ObjectTest('Paul', 'teacher');
var second = new ObjectTest('Jane', 'doctor');
var third = new ObjectTest('Mike', 'student');

var someArray = [];
someArray.push(first, second, third);

for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someArray[i].color = 'red';
}                                            // no semicolon here

console.log(someArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`<=` was rong

```js
var ObjectTest = function(something1, something2){
    this.Name = something1;
    this.Job = something2;
    this.color = '';
    this.numbers = [];
    
}

var first = new ObjectTest('Paul', 'teacher');
var second = new ObjectTest('Jane', 'doctor');
var third = new ObjectTest('Mike', 'student');

var someArray = [];
someArray.push(first, second, third);


for(var i =0; i < someArray.length; i++){
    someArray[i].color = 'red';
};
console.log(someArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<=` to `<` in your loop.

There's only 3 items on the array, meaning you have indexes `0`, `1` and `2`. The loop should stop when it arrives at at `3`. But since you used `<=` and not `<`, `i <= 3` when `i` is `3` is `true` thus executing the code. The error is caused by `someArray[3]` not existing.

A safer way to loop through arrays without dealing with indexes is to use `array.forEach`. It only loops as many times as there are items in the array.

```
someArray.forEach((object, index) => {
  object.color = 'red'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to go over an array is to use the forEach.
Something like this:

```
someArray.forEach(data =>  data.color = 'red');
```